# Lambda capture by default reference vs named

Tags: c++, lambda

What is the difference between using named capture for a lambda expression compared to reference by default?

Something like this:

```
std::vector<int> object;
std::vector<int> otherObject;

auto fun = [&](const int& i){ object.push_back(i); };
```

Compared to:

```
auto fun = [&object](const int& i){ object.push_back(i); };
```

Comment: There is no benefit in passing `int` as a const reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Explanation :

> [&] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by reference and current object by reference if exists

As long as your lambda only uses `object` the two examples are technically equivalent. However, they differ in that if you modify the lambdas such that they they require additional captured objects you will need to manually add them to the capture block of the second example but not the first.

Comment: So, the default by reference will only handle variables used in the lambda body for all cases? So no disadvantage to performance or anything else compared to the named case?

Comment: @CJ_macar That's what the documentation indicates.